# Having trouble with centering with Row widget

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I have a row widget and I want some `Text` to be in the very center or the `Row` and an `Icon` that will be to the left of it, and changing how far left the `Icon` is it is should not affect the position of the `Text`. Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 0.8,
      child: Container(
          color: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.egg)),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Text("TEST",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Color(0xffE0E0E0),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("TEST"),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Note that I haven't actually made any adjustments to try to create this effect. That is because everything I have tried does not work. Here is what I have tried:

1. Wrapped my `Text` in `Align` widget
2. Include `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` in `Row`. This will center the `Text` and `Icon`, but I cannot adjust the position of the `Icon` without affecting the position of the `Text` and will affect possible future additions to the `Row`
3. Wrap `Text` or/and `Padding` with `Center`. Both Icon and `Text` remain in the top left position
4. It's obvious that I've thought about using `Padding` but `Padding` doesn't seem to be a very good solution and doesn't seem to generalize well.

I also want to clarify that the problem is occurring in the `Row` that is furthest up. Any and all help and suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: like this type you want ? here below image link
https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/547818254988029952?codeId=Ml3m0a9OzXm9o&origin=imageurlgenerator

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) instead.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.8,
          child: Container(
              color: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        left: 0,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.egg)),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text("TEST",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  color: Color(0xffE0E0E0),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text("TEST"),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for `Expanded()`/`Spacer()` which allow proportionally sizing children of `Column` or a `Row`.

Updated code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 0.8,
      child: Container(
          color: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded( // added
                    child: Align( // added as well, because otherwise the Icon would be centered
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.egg)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Text("TEST",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              color: Color(0xffE0E0E0),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("TEST"),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Spacer(), // added
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```